Airflow | Store result of a BQ query to XCOM
In Airflow, I need to run a query (with some joins) on BigQuery tables. The query results in a single computed value. What is the best way to push this result to xcom? I have to use this result in the next task in pipeline.
I tried BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator but it's not pushing values to xcom.
Thank you.

Please post your DAG code and let us know what version of Airflow and the operators you are using! Without seeing your code, I can make a few suggestions, but they may be off base without more info

use the BigQueryInsertJobOperator instead - the BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator is deprecated
make sure you've modified the DAG to do an XCom push on the output of the query
consider using the Taskflow API instead of XCom

